# How to take an input and when the submit button is pressed put it into a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I got some HTML like this

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Mineral">
<input type = "submit">
```

I have no idea how to put what is in the text into a javascript variable when the submit button is pressed. I'll use jQuery if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.val()` to fetch the value of the input field.

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault(); // <-------- To stop form submission
   var txt = $("input[type=text]").val(); // <----- Fetch value of input field
   console.log(txt) // <----------- Check console has the value of the input field.

});
```